# I am misunderstanding something very fundamental about Antlr4

Tags: antlr, antlr4

So I have this test grammar:

```
grammar Test;

HELLO : 'Hello';
X : [a-z]+;
WS : [ ]+ -> skip;

test : HELLO X;
```

And I have this test string:

```
Hello buddy
```

But the grammar doesn't match the provided test string. It seems like it should be obvious that HELLO matches "Hello" and X matches "buddy". Once we have the token stream [HELLO, X] it should match parser rule "test".

This is coming from a much more complicated error based on a much more complicated grammar file. I managed to reproduce the bug with the simpler grammar you see above.

I am so confused right now.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the `Test` grammar, it parses `Hello buddy` just fine: https://pasteboard.co/htiLSjnklMu3.png

Comment: For debugging a grammar, print out the token stream and make sure the tokens and types are what you expect. Also it's best to make the start rule end with EOF `test: HELLO X EOF;` so the parser doesn't stop prematurely on the input.

Comment: @kaby76 After investigating this further, I found two issues. First, I was using http://lab.antlr.org/ for testing but forgot to clear the lexer input. That was causing the issue described above.  Second, in my personal code I had lexer rules ID and URI, but due to the way they interacted, every ID token was also a URI token. I redefined the URI token as a parser rule and now my code is running perfectly. Thanks for your help! This was driving me crazy.

Comment: @BartKiers Thank you so much for testing that for me. I found the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The above grammar and lexer rules parse the string as expected. If you use http://lab.antlr.org/ for testing, make sure you clear the lexer rules tab before entering a combined lexer/parser grammar under the parser tab.